# Flash doesn't work in Chrome: "Restart Chrome to enable Adobe Flash Player"

Tags: google-chrome, flash

Flash, or more precisely [Tidal](https://listen.tidal.com/) (the logged in version which runs on Flash), doesn't work in Google Chrome beta. The browser constantly displays the "Restart Chrome to enable Adobe Flash Player" modal but doesn't enable it after restart while Tidal urges me to activate Flash.

This is a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.04 with Google Chrome beta 61. On my old computer with the same Chrome and Ubuntu versions and the same Chrome profile (copied over) it all works fine, so I'm missing something simple because I don't remember doing anything hacky to enable Flash in Chrome. What can it be?

I have installed both adobe-flashplugin and pepperflashplugin-nonfree. I have installed the third party addons during the system installation. What can I be missing?

EDIT: I noticed that on my older computer there is an additional button in the location bar with a second question whether to allow Tidal to run Flash.

[image: location bar Flash/plugin button]

It's missing in the new setup.

[image: no additional info in the location bar]

In fact, Flash seems to be present and up-to-date but not used.

[image: Google Chrome components]

Answer (score 3):

The problem was entirely self-inflicted. While copying over my data from the other computer, I also copied Chrome's local installation of Flash in `$HOME/.config/google-chrome-beta/PepperFlash`. The solution is simple, delete it

```
rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome-beta/PepperFlash
```

visit a site requiring flash, wait until Chome asks you to restart, go back, it will work now.